# difference method in Linked-list outputting the wrong numbers and excluding the ones i want?

Tags: java, linked-list, logic

The difference method gets the two sets (setA – setB) includes those
elements from setA that are not in setB. For example, if setA contains `{1, 2, 3, 7}` and
setB contains `{1, 2, 4, 5}`, then the difference of these contains `{3, 7}`. The new set. However my method returns

> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 4 -> 4 -> 4 -> 4 -> 5 -> 5 -> 5 -> 5 ->

excluding `3` and `7`.

The other method `intersection()` works just fine.I thought by adding the '!' to line `if( current1.getItem().equals(current2.getItem())` would do the trick but i was mistaken.

```
package sets;
import exceptionclasses.EmptyCollectionException;
import sets.SetADT;
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedSet<E> implements SetADT<E>
{
    protected Node<E> front, rear; //references to the first and last nodes

    public LinkedSet()
    {
        front = rear = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node <E> aNode = new  Node <E>(element);
        if(isEmpty())
            front = aNode;
        else
            rear.setNext(aNode);
        rear = aNode;
    }

    @Override
    public E removeRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    E item;
    Node<E> temp;
    Node<E> current = front;
    int theNumber = rand.nextInt(size());

    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("LinkedSet");

    else if(current.getItem().equals(theNumber)){
        front = front.getNext();
        return (E) current;
    }
    //otherwise...
    else{
        while(current.getNext() != null && !current.getNext().getItem().equals(theNumber)){
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        temp = current.getNext();
        if(current.getNext().getNext() != null)
            current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        else
            current.setNext(null);
    }
    return (E) temp;

    }

    @Override
    public E remove(E element) throws EmptyCollectionException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    E item;
    Node<E> temp;
    Node<E> current = front;
    //if the list is empty
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("LinkedSet");
    //else if the first item is what you want to remove..
    else if(current.getItem().equals(element)){
        front = front.getNext();
        return (E) current;
    }
    //otherwise...
        else{
        while(current.getNext() != null && !current.getNext().getItem().equals(element)){
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        temp = current.getNext();
        if(current.getNext().getNext() != null)
            current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        else
            current.setNext(null);
        }
        return (E) temp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(E target) {

    Node<E> current = front;
    while(current != null && !current.getItem().equals(target)){

        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return current != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return front == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int size = 0;
    Node <E> current = front;
    while(current != null){
        size++;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return size;
    }

    public LinkedSet<E> intersection(LinkedSet<E> theSet2){
    Node <E> current1 = theSet2.front;
    Node <E>current2 = front;
    LinkedSet<E> aSet = new LinkedSet<E>();

    while(current1 != null ){
        current2 = front;
        while(current2 != null){
            if( current1.getItem().equals(current2.getItem())){ 
                aSet.add(current1.getItem());
            }
            current2 = current2.getNext();
        }
        current1 = current1.getNext();
    }
    return  aSet;
    }


    public LinkedSet<E> difference(LinkedSet<E> theSet2){
    Node <E> current1 = theSet2.front;
    Node <E>current2 = front;
    LinkedSet<E> aSet = new LinkedSet<E>();

    while(current1 != null ){
        current2 = front;
        while(current2 != null){
            if( !current1.getItem().equals(current2.getItem())){ //Here 
                aSet.add(current1.getItem());
            }
            current2 = current2.getNext();
        }
        current1 = current1.getNext();
    }
    return  aSet;
    }

    /**
    * toString method - returns a String representing the state of the queue
    * @return a string containing all items in the queue
    */
    public String toString()
    {
    String str = new String("");
    Node<E> current = front;
    while(current != null)
    {
        str += current.getItem()+ " -> " ;
        current = current.getNext();

    }
    return str;
    }





    }
```

I'm pulling me hair out on this one.

```
    package sets;

    public class Project3App {

public static <E> void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinkedSet <Integer> theSet = new LinkedSet <Integer>();
    LinkedSet <Integer> theSet2 = new LinkedSet <Integer>();

    theSet.add(1);
    theSet.add(2);
    theSet.add(3);
    theSet.add(7);

    theSet2.add(1);
    theSet2.add(2);
    theSet2.add(4);
    theSet2.add(5);


    System.out.println(theSet.difference(theSet2));



    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in this portion of code

```
while(current1 != null ){
        current2 = front;
        while(current2 != null){
            if( !current1.getItem().equals(current2.getItem())){ //Here 
                aSet.add(current1.getItem());
            }
            current2 = current2.getNext();
        }

        current1 = current1.getNext();
    }
```

So what you did  ( == mean equals method):

1. theSet.add(1) == theSet2.add(1); TRUE
2. theSet.add(1) == theSet2.add(2);  FALSE => add to result aSet
3. theSet.add(1) == theSet2.add(4);  FALSE => add to result aSet
4. theSet.add(1) == theSet2.add(5); FALSE => add to result aSet
5. theSet.add(2) == theSet2.add(1); FALSE => add to result aSet

and so go on....

You have to add the element only is not all present at all in current2.

The  logic is more like this :

```
 while(current1 != null){
             boolean found = false;
            current2 = front;
            while(current2 != null && !found){
                if(current1.getItem().equals(current2.getItem())){  
                    found = true;
                } else {
                   current2 = current2.getNext();
               }
            }
            if(!found){
               aSet.add(current1.getItem());
            }
            current1 = current1.getNext();
        }
```

Comment: it gives me an output of 4 -> 5 ->. I'm suppose to get 3 -> 7 ->.

Comment: You have inverse the local variables :  `Node <E> current1 = theSet2.front;
    Node <E>current2 = front;`  should be `Node <E> current1 = front;   Node <E>current2 = theSet2.front;`

Comment: Nothing shows up at all now. No matter i get 3,7 doing
System.out.println(theSet2.difference(theSet));
instead of 
System.out.println(theSet.difference(theSet2));